# Convert SQL DateTime format

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I display a `DATETIME` value (`2010-12-02 15:20:17.000`) as `02/12-2010 15:20`?

Comment: What database are you using? Why are you doing this in the database and not the application?

Comment: Do you *really* want `02/12-2010`? That seems bizarre mixing the slash and dash.

Comment: I came here from a google search for a different formatting string and found this: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx which helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server:

```
select stuff(convert(varchar, getdate(), 105), 3, 1, '/') + ' ' + left(convert(varchar, getdate(), 8), 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` is a `DateTime` is a `DateTime` - it just holds a date and time and doesn't have any string representation, really.

See the [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) topic in the SQL Server Books Online for details - it shows all supported date formats that SQL Server supports.

For your source format (`2010-12-02 15:20:17.000`) you could probably use style no. 121

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(50)
SET @source = '2010-12-02 15:20:17.000'

DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = CONVERT(DATETIME, @source, 121)

SELECT @Date
```

but your target format is a bit odd..... I don't see any "out of the box" style that would match your needs. You'll need to use some string manipulation code to get that exact format.

Comment: @RedFilter: yes, the style no. 121 is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)` which would match that, no ??

Answer (score 1):

Use MSSQL's build-in function to convert datetime to string with format,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1) AS [MM/DD/YY] --2/5/12
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] --5/2/2012
```

You need to create custom function to get various format to use like this;

```
SELECT dbo.ufn_FormatDateTime(GETDATE(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS tt')
--Output : 2012-02-05 01:58:38 AM

SELECT dbo.ufn_FormatDateTime(GETDATE(),'(dddd) mmmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt')
--Output : (Sunday) February 05, 2012 01:58:38.723 AM

SELECT dbo.ufn_FormatDateTime(GETDATE(),'dd/MM/yyyy')
--Output : 05/02/2012

SELECT dbo.ufn_FormatDateTime(GETDATE(),'yyyy MMM, dd (ddd) hh:mm:ss tt')
-- Output : 2012 Feb, 05 (Sun) 01:58:38 AM
```

Get the code snippet from this link. 
http://www.tainyan.com/codesnippets/entry-62/sql-server-date-time-format-function.html

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't see how this will work for an obviously mixed format, but thanks for sharing this; I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Oracle:

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, "dd/mm-yyyy HH24:mi")
    from DUAL;
```

Assuming SQL Server:

```
select STR(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), 2) 
        + '/' 
        + STR(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()), 2) 
        + '-' 
        + STR(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 4) 
        + ' ' 
        + STR(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()), 2) 
        + ':' 
        + STR(DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()), 2);
```

Comment: the OP indicates that he is using MS SQL

Comment: @Brad: Yes, I saw it after I write my response, so I just added a SQL Server solution. Thanks for telling me! =)

Answer (score 0):

Little example I use for Germany and Switzerland: dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 104) + ' ' + LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), 5)
```