# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have  this DOB column in my additional information table  with YYYY-MM-DD. I need to convert let say DOB: 1949-06-15 to DOB format: MM/DD/YYYY.

I have

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21, 101) as 'DOB'
```

but I still get this result: `1949-06-15`.

I even tried

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21, 101), '-', '/')
```

However, the result is `1949/06/15`.

I am looking for `06/15/1949` as the output. Can someone please help?

Comment: You should really store dates as dates or datetime (datetime2, etc.) instead of as strings.  Then, the format to display the date in is up to the front end, where it should be, and there's no ambiguity in the database side as to how to parse the string to get what you really need.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the reply.  Unfortunately, our application store all the DOB dates as YYYY-MM-DD in the database. I am trying to create a query to output an XML. For the DOB, the user wants this DOB format: MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert SQL DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336148/convert-sql-datetime-format)

Comment: DOB is stored in the  ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21 column.

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, it appears you're saving the string equivalent of the date. You could cast the string to the date datatype, then use the convert function for the format output.
For example:

```
DECLARE @mydate char(10) = '1949-06-15'
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(@mydate as date), 101)
```

Produces:

```
06/15/1949
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use REPLACE and CONVERT functions. Please try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, '2010-02-11', 120), 101), '/', '-')
```

Edit: Just noticed, you want `/` instead of `-` in your output seems like. In this case, please just remove replace, like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, '2010-02-11', 120), 101)
```

P.S. Assumed that you are using Sql Server 2008.

Edit 2: Since you are receiving the date value from an attribute of another table, you will need to use something like below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime,  ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21, 120), 101)
from ai
```

Assuming ai is the table name. If it is not, use the table name with the alias of ai, like:

```
from tablename ai
```

Comment: Thanks, Eray. Yes, I am using SQL Server 2008. DOB dates are stored in the addlinfo_index_21. When our applications stores them it has the YYYY-MM-DD format. How do I convert them to MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: Please try the one-line query in my answer, the bottom one. it is doing what you are asking.

Comment: DOB is stored in the ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21 column

Comment: Then when you try this, change `'2010-02-11'` in his example to `ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21` ?

Comment: It works.....I just tried REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, ai.ADDLINFO_INDEX_21, 120), 101), '-', '/') and getting 06/15/1949.....Thanks for your help!!! You rock!!!!

Comment: I am happy to help. I'd appreciate if you select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the "tick" on the left. Regards. @Les